# Pack labels right next to entry box in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, pack, tkinter-entry

I have a window that prompts users to enter the directory of their log files.
However, my label seems to pack on top of my entrybox. Any idea on how to pack them side by side?

```
labelText=StringVar()

labelText.set("Enter directory of log files")

labelDir=Label(app,textvariable=labelText,height=4)

labelDir.pack()

directory=StringVar(None)

dirname=Entry(app,textvariable=directory,width=50)

dirname.pack()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you need to set the `side` option to "left".  See below:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, StringVar

app = Tk()

labelText=StringVar()
labelText.set("Enter directory of log files")
labelDir=Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=4)
labelDir.pack(side="left")

directory=StringVar(None)
dirname=Entry(app,textvariable=directory,width=50)
dirname.pack(side="left")

app.mainloop()
```

example:

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2):

You could always switch to using '.grid' instead.

With your code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, StringVar

app = Tk()

labelText=StringVar()
labelText.set("Enter directory of log files")
labelDir=Label(app, textvariable=labelText, height=4)
labelDir.grid(row=1,column=1)

directory=StringVar(None)
dirname=Entry(app,textvariable=directory,width=50)
dirname.grid(row=1,column=2)

app.mainloop()
```

Code Running: 
https://gyazo.com/7c78e6f3d7c8fe9233f150072c44a0d1